# AWK: return value to shell script

Tags: bash, awk

Is it possible to have an awk command within a bash script return values to a bash variable, i.e.,if my awk script does some arithmetic operations, can I store the answers in variables so, they can be accessed in the bash script. If possible, how to distinguish between multiple return variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. You can use `exit` to return an error code, but in general you can't modify the shell environment from a subprocess.

You can also, of course, print the desired content in awk and put it into variables in bash by using `read`:

```
read a b c <<< $(echo "foo" | awk '{ print $1; print $1; print $1 }')
```

Now `$a`, `$b` and `$c` are all 'foo'. Note that you have to use the `<<<$()` syntax to get read to work. If you use a pipeline of any sort a subprocess is created too and the environment `read` creates the variables in is lost when the pipeline is done executing.

Comment: how? can you give an example please. Thanks

Comment: @ShuvoShams: I added one, hope it helps.

Comment: @EduardoIvanec - modifying a parent process' environment (variables) is so difficult that it might as well be declared "near impossible".

Comment: @AndrewBeals: do you have a link to one of the difficult ways? I know you can pass a pointer to the current environment in some low level Unix syscalls, but I don't know of any way to do this in the shell level.

Comment: @EduardoIvanec Actually, the last time I wanted to do something like that, it involved digging in the process table to find where the parent was located, then mucking about in /dev/mem directly.  You can't get access to your parent's address space unless you're root and you dig about in the system's memory space, or if the parent explicitly shares it with you via the shared memory syscalls — and at that point, you might as well declare some sort of interface and pass the information around with proper IPC calls.

Comment: +1 Another technique is to have the awk script output bash commands that you can source: `source <(awk '{...processing...} END {print "a=" a_val ";b=" b_val ";c=" c_val}')`

Comment: Thanks Glenn, but, getting error messages while executing. I have two variables, one updating the input file (if condition is met) as each record is updated and other keeping a counter. Currently, my redirection is not working right either. Here is the code: source <(awk '{BEGIN {ct=0}{if($1 < 100) ct++ else if ($3 > 100) $3=sprintf("%.1f",$3/100);print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3;} END{print ct}' $f_name > tmp.stat && mv tmp.stat $f_name . Will very much appreciate some pointers

Comment: I had to change the command to `read -d '' a b c <<< $(echo "foo" | awk '{ print $1; print $1; print $1 }')` to make it work.

Answer (score 8):

```
var=$(awk '{ print $1}')
```

This should set var to the output of awk. Then you can use string functions or whatever from there to differentiate within the value or have awk print only the part you want.

Comment: This to me is the simplest answer and worked for what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but there's another way to do this that's worked really well for me, and that's using an unused file descriptor. We all know stdin (&0), stdout (&1), and stderr (&2), but as long as you redirect it (aka: use it), there's no reason you can't use fd3 (&3).

The advantage to this method over other answers is that your awk script can still write to stdout like normal, but you also get the result variables in bash.

In your awk script, at the end, do something like this:

```
END {
  # print the state to fd3
  printf "SUM=%s;COUNT=%s\n", tot, cnt | "cat 1>&3"
}
```

Then, in your bash script, you can do something like this:

```bash
awk -f myscript.awk <mydata.txt 3>myresult.sh
source myresult.sh
echo "SUM=${SUM} COUNT=${COUNT}"
```